# Trace of matrix which equals to number of columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

While studying linear algebra, I found that:

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ Matrix (with $m>n$) then the trace $tr(A(A^T A)^{-1} A^T)$ equals the number of columns of $A$.

Does this hold in general and if so: why?

If the number of columns is 1, the trace seems to be 1, too.

I think that each columns acts like some kind of adding 1, but I can't explain why.

Comment: Can you think of a simple example of a square matrix that has its trace equals to its number of column (or line) ?

Comment: This of course requires that $A$ has full column rank, so that the matrix $A^TA$ is invertible.  Therefore this does not hold in general even when $m>n$.  Simplest counter-example:  zero matrix.

Comment: Well, $A^tA$ is regular $\iff$  $A$ has linearly independents columns. Then when the OP write $A(A^tA)^{-1}A^{t}$ is natural the assumption that $A$ has linearly independents columns. On other hand, just to complement the answer already given notice that $P:=A(A^tA)^{-1}A^t$ is a projection matrix onto the column spaces of $A$, that is, onto $C(A)$.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This community has been very helpful for my math studies :)

Comment: Let $A^+$ denote the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$, then a general result is
$$\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{trace}(AA^+)$$
If $A$ has full column rank then
$\;A^+=(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\;$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might already know that $tr(CD) = tr(DC)$ (if not try proving it with the definition of the trace). Now take $C := A$ and $D := (A^T A)^{-1} A^T$ and apply said rule. Now think about what $(A^T A)^{-1}$ is (supposing that $(A^T A)$ is invertible).

Solution:

> $tr(A(A^T A)^{-1} A^T) = tr((A^T A)^{-1} A^T A) = tr(Id_n) = n = \text{Number of columns}$

Comment: Wow thanks for the simple clear answer. I got it have a good day!